# Print first word after a match that is first word before another match

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have the following code that prints the first word after a match.

**Input**

```
MY_TYPE_A_T -- stuff, other stuff, more stuff, ..., Array of MY_TYPE_T in random.h
```

**Command**

```
    sed -n 's/.*Array of //p' \ # matches Array of
      | cut -d ' ' -f 1         # prints first word after Array of
```

**Output**

```
MY_TYPE_T
```

This works fine, but the problem is when I receive an input line with an n-dimensional array:

```
MY_TYPE_A_T -- stuff, other stuff, more stuff, ..., Array of Array of MY_TYPE_T in random.h
```

If I left the code alone, it would print `Array` when I really wanted `MY_TYPE_T`.  Keep in mind the input line could also be something like `Array of Pointer to Struct of Array of Pointer to, ..., MY_TYPE_T in random.h`.

All I want to do is print the first word before `in`, but only if it occurred after a match of `Array of`.

Is there an elegant way to print the first word (`MY_TYPE_T`) after a match (`Array of`) before another match (`in`).

Comment: Please post a *verifiable* example. With your sample string, your code returns the expected result (since `.*` is greedy). Also, you don't have to use `cut`, `sed` alone should be able to do that.

Comment: If you're considering answering this question please read the text very carefully as [when I tried to help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49467729/1745001) I apparently misunderstood the requirements and was told by the poster `You completely ignored the last two sentences of the OP. Reading isn't that hard, dude`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed -nre 's/.*Array of.*\s(\S*)\s+in\s.*/\1/p'`

Explanation: `-r` specifies using extended regular expressions. More readable, less portable.

The first greedy capture (`.*`) eats anything it can, so it eats all the text up to the last instance of `Array of`. Then, we eat the part after that `Array of` trying to capture any section of consecutive non-whitespace characters (`(\S+)`) surrounded by whitespace (`\s`), then followed by the word `in`, more whitespace, then anything until the end of the line. We then print the capture (`\1/p`).

Your description doesn't make it clear if there needs to be a filename after `in`, if these parts need to be in the end, or what the types / filenames might contain. Also, you really should try to

1. Write the question better. E.g.

   - You have a decent summary of what you actually want at the end, it would be better placed early in the text (people, especially engineers, are lazy. They won't read further than they think they need to in order to answer the question.)
   - Include more / better examples.
2. Be constructive and respectful in your replies. Comments such as “Reading isn't that hard, dude” isn't likely to earn you many upvotes...

Comment: Where does this `sed` command handle the word `in` as specified in the question?

Comment: The script doesn't need to handle the word `in` to produce the output you said you wanted (`MY_TYPE_T`) from the sample input that you provided (`MY_TYPE_A_T -- stuff, other stuff, more stuff, ..., Array of Array of MY_TYPE_T in random.h`). If there are cases when it's necessary to test for the word `in` then you should include them in the sample input/output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -n 's/.*Array of \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' file
MY_TYPE_T
```

If that isn't what you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: That is not what was asked and the above fails on the input string given in the question: `Array of Pointer to Struct of Array of Pointer to, ..., MY_TYPE_T in random.h` returns `Pointer` when the expected output is `MY_TYPE_T`.

There is no reason to edit the question.  The input/output is already sufficiently clear.

Comment: The regular expression needs to take into account the word `in` as stated in the OP and title: "All I want to do is print the first word before `in`, but only if it occurred after a match of Array of".

Comment: @MrPickles 1) There's nothing in the question to indicate that the output of the case you mention should be MY_TYPE_T instead of Pointer, and 2) no it doesn't, the OP just thought it did. 3) If neither of the currently posted answers do what the OP wants then the input/output is obviously **not** sufficiently clear since that'd mean at least 2 people misunderstood it.

Comment: @EdMorton Huh?  By that logic, at least two people did understand it. MrPickles came to a correct conclusion.

Comment: You completely ignored the last two sentences of the OP.  Reading isn't that hard, dude.

Comment: @EdMorton Nothing to indicate the output should be `MY_TYPE_T`?  Hello, look at the title and as lolol pointed out the last two sentences of the OP.

Comment: @lololololol you're counting yourself as 1 of the 2 people who understood what you wanted and even if 2 people did understand what you wanted, is understandable by 50% of the people who read it REALLY the bar you're shooting for when you ask questions? Also wrt " Reading isn't that hard, dude." - getting snotty with people trying to help you but who misunderstand your vague, rambling requirements is about as classless as you can get. Nice.

Comment: @MrPickles people posting questions frequently tell us lots of things they "need" which they absolutely don't need, they're just focused on trying to implement the specific solution that they came up with for their problem as they couldnt come up with a better solution which is why they're asking the question. The supporting text can/should be helpful but the only concrete thing we have to work with is the [mcve] that the poster provides and in this case hers was apparently inadequate to demonstrate her real requirements. See [ask] if that's unclear.